# Why does switching the position of async code cause infinite execution in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, event-loop

In the code below, I try to

- Connect a WebSocket client to a WebSocket server
- Connect the socket client to a socket server
  with different orders.

In the `promise1`, the order of connection is:

1. Connect a WebSocket client to a WebSocket server.
2. Connect socket client to a socket server.
   And the `promise1` never resolved.

In the `promise2`, the order of connection is:

1. Connect socket client to a socket server.
2. Connect a WebSocket client to a WebSocket server.
   And the `promise2` is resolved.

```js
import * as net from 'node:net';
import fs from 'fs';
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const testWSPort = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
const testSocketPath = `/tmp/test-${testWSPort}.sock`;

(async () => {
  if (fs.existsSync(testSocketPath)) {
    fs.unlinkSync(testSocketPath);
  }

  await startWSS({ port: testWSPort });
  (await startUnixDomainSocketServer(testSocketPath)).server;
  console.time('wsClient');
  const wsClient = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:${testWSPort}`);
  console.time('socketClient');
  const socketClient = net.createConnection({ path: testSocketPath });

  const promise1 = new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await new Promise<void>((done) => {
      wsClient.on('open', () => {
        done();
      });
      wsClient.on('error', done);
    });

    await new Promise<void>((done) => {
      socketClient.on('connect', done);
      socketClient.on('error', done);
      socketClient.on('timeout', done);
    });

    resolve();
  });

  const promise2 = new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
    await new Promise<void>((done) => {
      socketClient.on('connect', done);
      socketClient.on('error', done);
      socketClient.on('timeout', done);
    });

    await new Promise<void>((done) => {
      wsClient.on('open', done);
      wsClient.on('error', done);
    });

    resolve();
  });

  const promise3 = Promise.all([
    new Promise<void>((done) => {
      socketClient.on('connect', () => {
        console.timeEnd('socketClient');
        done();
      });
      socketClient.on('error', done);
      socketClient.on('timeout', done);
    }),

    new Promise<void>((done) => {
      wsClient.on('open', () => {
        console.timeEnd('wsClient');
        done();
      });
      wsClient.on('error', done);
    }),
  ]);

  promise1.then(() => {
    console.log('Why does this line never executed?');
  });
  promise2.then(() => {
    console.log('But this line executed!');
  });
  promise3.then(() => {
    console.log('This line also executed');
  });
})();

function startWSS({ port }: { port: number }) {
  const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port });
  wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('error', console.error);
  });

  return new Promise<WebSocketServer>((resolve, reject) => {
    wss.on('listening', () => {
      resolve(wss);
    });

    wss.on('error', reject);
  });
}

function startUnixDomainSocketServer(
  socketPath: string
): Promise<{ server: net.Server }> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const server = new net.Server();

    server.listen(socketPath, () => {
      resolve({ server });
    });

    server.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

### My questions

Why is `promise1` never resolved?

Why change the position of this order cause this difference?

You can try this code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ervgkg?file=index.ts

### What I have tried

I think this is a problem related to node.js event loop. I read [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick), but I still can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Because you attach the events afetr you awaited for the other round of events. So the wsClient event certainly fire after the socketClient ones, and thus by the time you do attach the socketClient event listeners, the events already did fire and your listeners are never called. Attach all the events, then await for both Promises.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your comment. You are right! I did a simple bench mark. It turns out that wsClient `open` event always fires after the socketClient `connect` event. Problem solved. Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: For starters, [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!